# How to create an Outlook contact group from a list of mail recipients?

Tags: contacts, address-book, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a mail with a list of recipients I would like to create an address book contact group from, but the only way I can find is to copy and add each one individually. Surely there is a way to copy the whole recipient list into a contact group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/484) works in Outlook 2010; don't see why it wouldn't in Outlook 2013 as well:

1. Right click on a recipient in the message header in the **Reading Pane**
2. From the context menu that pops-up, choose **Select All**, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy them or right click on the selected addresses and choose Copy

   [image: 1]
3. Open your **Contact Group** or create a new one via `New Items / More Items / Contact Group` (or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
4. Press the **Add Members** button and select **From Address Book**
5. Place your cursor in the field next to the **Members** button and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copied addresses
6. Press **OK** and the addresses will be added to the Contact Group

You can repeat the steps above if multiple addresses have been added to both the **To** and **CC** fields.